# Toggle on/off using addEventListener instead of OnClick

Tags: javascript, events

The goal here is to completely get rid of onclick in HTML and execute the function in JS instead through EventListener

Here is the short code below:

HTML

```
<button id="Toggle" onClick="MovelistShowHide('movelist')">Toggle Movelist On/Off</button>
    <div id="movelist">
        Movelist content
    </div>
```

CSS

```
 #movelist{display:none; background-color: lime;}
```

JS

```
function MovelistShowHide(element) {
  var srcElement = document.getElementById(element);
  if (srcElement != null) {
    if (srcElement.style.display == "block") {
      srcElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
      srcElement.style.display = 'block';
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't know how many buttons/text divs you might end up having, and you're already using CSS, I would suggest switching to classes - one to define the style of the text div(s), and another one that defines `display: block` called "show".

When the button is clicked you can use the [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) on the button's [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling) (ie the text div) to toggle the "show" class on and off.

```js
// Cache the buttons
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

// Add listeners to all of the them
buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', toggleText);
});

// When a button is clicked toggle "show" class
// using the classList on the button's next element
// sibling (which is the text div)
function toggleText() {
  this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

```css
.text { display: none; background-color: lime; padding: 0.25rem; margin: 0.25rem 0;}
.show { display: block; }
```

```html
<section>
  <button type="button">Toggle 1 text</button>
  <div class="text">Text 1 content</div>
</section>

<section>
  <button type="button">Toggle 2 text</button>
  <div class="text">Text 2 content</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

look at code

```
<button id="Toggle" >Toggle Movelist On/Off</button>
  <div id="movelist">
     Movelist content
   </div>


const btn = document.getElementById('Toggle');
 btn.addEventListener('click',function (e){
  var srcElement = document.getElementById("movelist");
    if (srcElement != null) {
     if (srcElement.style.display == "block") {
      srcElement.style.display = 'none';
      }
      else {
      srcElement.style.display = 'block';
     }
     return false;
    }
  } );
```

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER

```
const btn = document.getElementById('Toggle');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const move = document.getElementById('movelist');

  if (move.style.display === 'block') {
    move.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    move.style.display = 'block';
  }
});
```